# How to get pyFFTW running?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, fftw, pyfftw

I am basically looking for a faster alternative to `scipy.fftpack.fft` and found `pyFFTW`.

However, I am about to despair since no matter what I am trying I am not getting `pyFFTW` to work.

What I did so far:

- installed `pyFFTW` by means of `PIP`: `pip install pyfftw`
- downloaded FFTW 3.3.5 for Windows from [here](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html)
- extracted the zip file and copied anything to the site-package directory of `pyFFTW`

As soon as I try to import `pyFFTW`, the following exception occurs:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] 

on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyfftw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyfftw\__init__.py", line 16, in <module> from .pyfftw import (
  File "__init__.pxd", line 861, in init pyfftw.pyfftw (C:\projects

\pyfftw\pyfftw\pyfftw.c:17297)

ValueError: numpy.ufunc has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 104, got 112
```

I am using `numpy 1.7.1`.

Any suggestions about how to fix this problem are highly appreciated.

BTW: I already tried to uninstall / install numpy and `pyFFTW` several times.

Comment: I would recommend sticking with either pip or downloading pyFFT from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyFFTW. Which version of pyFFT are you using?

Comment: I have downloadef the latest version of pyfftw using pip.

Comment: Can you type "pyfftw.__version__" in a python shell and post the output please

Comment: This command does not work but pip freeze returns pyFFTW=0.10.4

Comment: May it be necessary to upgrate to a more up-to-date numpy version?

Comment: Since Numpy 1.10.4 and above importing of pyfftw is possible. Unfortunately I cannot upgrade... In the documentation of pyfftw it is written that it should work with Numpy versions > 1.6...

Comment: Why can't you upgrade nunpy?

Comment: Because of incompatibilities with other Python packages we are using.

Comment: Try compiling it with your version of numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade numpy. Whatever binary you found was compiled against a too-new copy of numpy.